# Link generator GetUriByName() returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got a `ProfileController` with the endpoint:

```
[HttpPut]
[SwaggerOperation("Confirm profile e-mail")]
[Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]
[Route("profile/e-mail")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ExecutionResult), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmProfileEmail(string token, int userId)
{
    //var requestResult = await _mediator.Send(request);

    //return this.FromExecutionResult(requestResult);
    return Ok(token);
}
```

Meanwhile, I have `HttpContextAccessor` and `LinkGenerator` injected into my service. When I try to generate the confirmation link, I keep getting `null`, but don't understand what do I do wrong:

```
var confirmationLink =
    _linkGenerator.GetUriByName(
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext,
        "/profile/e-mail",
        new { token, userId = newUser.Id });
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give some clarificaton to working with `LinkGenerator`, as there is not so much documentation related to this class, especially with examples...

Comment: I believe the problem is that `GetUriByName` requires the endpoint name, not the route. The name being a property of the route attribute, for example: `[Route("profile/e-mail", Name = "ProfileEmail")]`. When calling `GetUriByName` you would pass "ProfileEmail" as the name.

Comment: Post it as the answer. It helped!

Comment: That worked? Good deal. I wasn't sure since I haven't worked with named routes since MVC4-ish, but that's how it used to be so I figured it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetUriByName` requires the endpoint name, not the route. The name being a property of the route attribute, for example: `[Route("profile/e-mail", Name = "ProfileEmail")]`. When calling `GetUriByName` you would pass "ProfileEmail" as the name.